# mvc jqgrid: jQGrid displays NaN for the amounts on hosting in IIS server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, mvcjqgrid

Currently, I am looking at the reporting module of a software which was developed by the another developer(unavailable now). He have used both **jQgrid** as well as **jQGrid for asp.net mvc**. There is no data rendering problem in the sales report using the pure jQgrid. But he have used jQGrid for asp.net mvc for the Trial balance purpose.

It works fine and shows the data on the local host. But on deploying in the company's IIS server, the fields values are displayed as "NaN".

**In Localhost**
[image]

**In IIS Server**
[image]

If any body have encountered this problem before, please share your thoughts and view.

Comment: Id `Dr Amount` a calculated value (for example `0/0` will result in `NaN`)?

Comment: Everything is extracted from database and mapped in the respective columns only.

Comment: You should include **more details** in the text of your question. It's unclear which version of jqGrid you use, from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). Moreover it's unclear **how you use jqGrid** (you posted no JavaScript code and no test data). The best would be if you prepared the demo which demonstrates the problem and one could debut it to see where exactly NaN will be set.

Comment: Seems like culture is different in your development and live environment. Try setting the culture explicitly in code, for example in the controller that's responsible for exposing the data to the grid. It is very well possible the culture of live environment is different from development environment.

Comment: @Robin van der Knaap thanks .. I changed the culture of the live environment and the problem is solved now.